# RSpec: Is there a not for `and change`, e.g. `and_not to change`?

Tags: rspec

I find the `.and` method very useful for chaining many expectations.

```
expect {
  click_button 'Update Boilerplate'
  @boilerplate_original.reload
} .to  change { @boilerplate_original.title }.to('A new boilerplate')
  .and change { @boilerplate_original.intro }.to('Some nice introduction')
```

Is there something that let's me check for **no change**?

```
.and_not change { @boilerplate_original.intro }
```

Something like that? I couldn't find anything, and it's hard to search on Google for something like "and not".

Comment: If all you need is an integer, you can say: `expect {my_action}
      .to change {some_action}.from(0).to(1)
      .and (change{another_action}.by(0))` without redefining anything.

Answer (score 51):

No, there is no `and_not` and no general negation operator, as discussed in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/493

There is, however, a mechanism to define a negated version of an existing matcher, as described in http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers.define_negated_matcher, which you can use with `and`.

The full set of compound matchers is documented at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/compound-expectations

Comment: tldr; put `RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_change, :change` in `spec_helper.rb`

Answer (score 38):

If you are trying to assert that some operation should not change a count, you could do

```
expect { something }.to change { Foo.count }.by(1).and change { Bar.count }.by(0)
```

Comment: issue beeing with rspec-rubocop, there is a (IMO legit) cop that encourages you to use negative matcher instead of "change by 0"

Answer (score 13):

You can define a negate matcher by `RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher`

Example

```
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_include, :include
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_eq, :eq
```

Place this line in the beginning of file outside any context, place in another file and load that file to your test

So now you can write

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to include(1).and not_include(5).and not_include(6)
expect(100).to eq(100).and not_eq(200)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is buried in a comment by @stevenspiel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967391/rspec-is-there-a-not-for-and-change-e-g-and-not-to-change#comment82631493_34969429), so I'll just quote the comment: "tldr; put `RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_change, :change` in `spec_helper.rb`"

You can then do `.and not_change(obj, :msg)`. For example, `.and not_change(@boilerplate_original, :intro)`